# How to make requests to a web page from an Android app

Tags: android

There is a [web page](http://connect.inmarsat.com/Services/Land/IsatPhone/SMS/sms.html) that has a web service which sends text messages to mobile devices, the service is not my property, I do not know the source code and therefore I do not know how it is handled internally, in that page a form is filled out and When you click on the button to send this, send the form to the server so that the information is processed.

I need to pass this web service to an android app to send this type of requests to the page from the app.

Another doubt that I have the data structure, when clicking with the mouse on the page I have obtained this code that supposedly contains the data structure but I can not find exactly which are the mobile number, the mail account and the message

The data structure is:

```
server=gsps.ashx
name="to" value="+8707712345678" 
name="reply_email" value="qq@qq.com" 
name="message" value="Hola Mundo"
```

I have tried to implement this using `httpHandler` but I do not know how to verify that the message has been sent and I can not capture the server's answer either, someone tell me how to do it.

Here the httpHandler class:

```
public class httpHandler {
public String post(String posturl){
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(posturl);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to","+870776458585"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reply_email","qq@qq.com"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message","Hola Mundo!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();/*y obtenemos una respuesta*/
        String text = EntityUtils.toString(ent);
        return text;
    }
  catch(Exception e) { return "error";}
 }
}
```

Here the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mDumpTextView;
private ScrollView mScrollView;
private EditText mTextoEditor1;
private Button mBotonSend;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    mBotonSend = (Button) findViewById( R.id.bt2_SendButton );

    mBotonSend.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            httpHandler handler = new httpHandler();
            String txt = handler.post("https://gsps.ashx");

        }
    } );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just load webview.Create a webview in your layout file and load the webview with your required URL.

Comment: `sachinmaharjan`, Yes, I do it using webview, but the presentation is very poor, I would like to customize this presentation

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it if this text is come in JSON then you can use it.

```
Html.fromHtml("Your string");
```

Comment: `yogesh kulkarni`, please you can more detailed the example, it seems to me that the data structure can be obtained by clicking on the web page mentioned at the beginning